# Unconventional Reproductive Methods?

Tags: internal-consistency, reproduction

There are a lot of [reproduction methods](https://www.boundless.com/biology/textbooks/boundless-biology-textbook/animal-reproduction-and-development-43/reproduction-methods-237/types-of-sexual-and-asexual-reproduction-885-12136/) in the world, some are weird like budding or the nightmare that is the seahorse. But an alien world would be unlikely to have any of the ones we see on earth, so what are some unconventional or other worldly methods of reproduction?

The creatures I need for this are a sort of pseudocentaurs, they mainly walk on all six limbs but they can use just 4 (think chimp or gorilla) They will preferably give birth to some type of egg-like object and only once in their life. I do need for them to be sapient but not dominant.

Assume that alien cells reproduce by division as do terrestrial cells.

---

Edit: this question differs from the one you claim its duplicating because sexual reproduction can be an answer.

Comment: This seems really, really broad.

Comment: How can I narrow it?

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what the creatures are like.

Comment: Ok give me a minute.

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25296/method-to-share-genetics-beyond-traditional-sexual-reproduction May have some useful ideas for you.

Comment: "They will preferably give birth...only once in their life" - That does seem to limit the survival chances of the species somewhat - no chance of an heir and a spare.

Comment: Unless each birth contains more than one child

Comment: The [Anglerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglerfish#Reproduction) has a highly unusual mating method. The male bites the female, and suddenly his lips fuse with the female and he slowly melts into the female's body. By the way, I don't really see why it'd be unlikely for an alien to use any reproduction found on Earth. Cell division is pretty much one of the simplest reproduction methods, one I'd expect to see in alien cells too.

Comment: That assumes alien cells work the same as earth cells

Comment: *How can I narrow it?* What are you really looking for? The most unusual method (by what possible metric)? The most reasonable for your creatures (we need more detail on them)? One that fits your narrative needs (which is where I've got to assume your 'one reproductive event per lifetime' comes from)? Is it the combination of parental material that you're looking for, since you've already specified that you want an egg-like birth?

Comment: Do you have a preference for asexual, sexual, or polysexual reproduction for these creatures? (I don't even know if that last one's a thing, but it certainly *could* be.)

Comment: *"They can use just four...."* Are you saying two are vestigal and pretty-useless, or that they prefer walking on six but will walk on four when they have other use for the fifth and sixth? If that's the case is the location of the multimodal limbs known?

Comment: @Nolonar I think that's a fine answer, rather than a comment. I hope you'll post it as such if the question is reopened.

Comment: @nitsua60 I mean that that front 2 limbs can be used as arms or legs

Comment: Are the forelimbs as facile as an ape's, or more like raccoon-level dexterity? Or are they horse-like limbs lashing out while the centaur-creature stays stable on four legs, rather than rearing like a horse?

Comment: They work in the fashion human hands do but with 2 thumbs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at what is required for reproduction.  The combination of genetic matter is only the first and in some cases less important stage.  What really gets interesting us the number of ways that are used to protect and nourish the offspring until they are old enough to fend for themselves.

Most animals use a variation of the egg.  A protective coating which contains the nourishment which the young consume until they outgrow their egg.  Mammals are the only creatures which don't use a variation on eggs; they use their own bodies to protect and to nourish.

So ask yourself this; what environmental dangers would a young alien face and what would evolve as protection?  And at the same time, what would it consume.

Let's create a species which is made up of psychic energy.  It lives in a plane of psychic energy, hunted by psychic predators.  Infant creatures might be attached to another creature which would mask its tiny psychic signature, and which could absorb energy waste from that species.  Or infants might have multiple stages, the first being a psychic dead stage that consumed physical nutrients.

Now, this doesn't fit what you were looking for but the idea is to think about 1. what are the threats to the young and what would most effectively protect them and 2. what do they consume?

Creatures that give birth only once in their lives are doomed to become extinct rather quickly, unless you meant that the birth event happens only once but produces multiple offspring.

What if the creatures died and at that time if their flesh was not too badly damaged, the dormant eggs inside their bodies would be triggered to start developing.  They would consume the flesh of their progenitor and eventually eat their way out.

Dying adults would instinctively seek a place where their flesh would be protected (maybe seeking caves or digging their own graves or burrows and sealing themselves in).  There might be some sort of ceremony involved as the creatures' society got more sophisticated and the tribe developed ways to protect the lives of their future members.

Or did you want the adults to survive their single birth event?  If there would never be more than one chance to reproduce, the instinct to protect their offspring would be even greater than it would in another species who expects to reproduce many times.  Maybe as each egg is produced it is attached to the adult's body, where it grows a proboscis which is inserted into the adult's body.  Then an armor plating of mud is applied over the top and turns into something as tough as cement.  When the young are old enough they must be chiseled out, or perhaps they have their own tools (a beak which is discarded after "birth") to break out.

In any case, from an evolutionary point of view once the single use species has reproduced there's no reason for it to live any longer.  The only exception I can think of would be if it was a sentient species, whose education is so complex that simple instinct does not suffice, and if there are no other methods for that learning available (community which can educate the young, extremely strong racial memory, young consume the memories of their progenitor telepathically or by consuming its flesh, etc)

Comment: This gave me some great mind food

Answer (score 2):

What about this: One partner loses a limb (that's specifically made for that purpose) and the other partner eats that limb. The special limb contains the eggs, and the saliva of the eating partner contains the sperm; the two come together during the eating. The eggs survive the stomach and develop in the intestines, where they take some of the food the parent eats, until the newborn leave the body the same way as the digestion waste does.

The evolutionary advantage is that the limb gives extra energy to the childbearing party (which is the male in this case), increasing the likelihood that he survives long enough for the offspring to develop and get born (it's a world with food scarcity).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Francine DeGrood Taylor's excellent answer, perhaps the child is born as the sapient-twin of a ferocious and protective guardian creature which matures within hours of birth, then spends its entire 9 month lifespan foraging for food to feed the child, and protecting them both from predators.  The non-sapient twin thereby serves as a pro-active egg, allowing the parent to produce young even when that parent isn't nutritionally healthy enough to produce a nutrient rich egg.

However, the math doesn't work!

If each member of your species can only have one child, then your species population can never grow.  It can only shrink.
For any given member of your species, there are only two possibilities.  It will die before it produces a child, or it will die after it produces a child.
If it dies after producing a child, it leaves its child behind to replace itself in the population.  If it dies before, the potential for a child is lost, so the population shrinks.
Such a species would die out as soon as the statistical probability of pre-parental death consumes the original population level.
That doesn't mean that the species couldn't exist.  It could have been manufactured in vast quantities during its genesis story.  But it is a species with a built in expiration date, and if it is sapient, then it will know that extinction is coming.  That realization will have ramifications throughout the species culture, religions and moral codes.

Comment: I think you should move your last paragraph up to the first. That way your answer reads as *answer-followed-by-reality-check*, rather than *frame-challenge-followed-by-answer-to-question-I-just-claimed-is-nonsense*.

Comment: @Henry Taylor, very true analysis of the species' probable future (or lack thereof).  I started thinking...how could the reproduce only once situation work, and then this thought occurred to me.  What if the creatures were immortal?  Or virtually immortal.  The total number of them is increasing because although only one offspring is produced, the progenitor doesn't die.  So the species is, in reality, dying out but the population is growing.

Comment: Oh, here's another interesting thought.  What if, after reproducing, the spent adult metamorphosed into something else, maybe something completely unrecognizable as being related to the "first stage" form.  It might even go through multiple life stages.  And maybe it will, occasionally, spontaneously revert to its first form and become once again able to reproduce (A little like how frogs can spontaneously change sex in response to species gender needs) if the population of this "first form" drops down low enough.

Comment: That would make them immune to both overpopulation and (barring a disaster of unmentionable proportions) extinction.  A self adjusting species.

Comment: Okay...now I've got to use this idea in my next novel... :)