# Which environment would favor sequential sexes as default?

Tags: fauna, reproduction, sex, gender

A couple of years ago, I [posted my idea](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/29258/11787) of *diachronic hermaphrodites* as an answer. In brief, an alien or fantasy species of sentient humanoids goes through up to five phases in life: presexual kids, gynosexual juniors, intersexual adults, androsexual matures and postsexual seniors. Procreation happens exclusively between juniors and matures, although sexual intercourse is also possible between members of other phases.

However, while I believe this could work well for a human-like species, I assume – without intervention of a higher being – it would only develop in a world where it’s the/a common sexual model. The actual evolution on Earth seems to suggest that sequential hermaphroditism is only beneficial in special cases, as it almost only happens in fish (and non-vertebrates). There, apparently, size plays a major role because older individuals grow large enough to either a) produce eggs which are much larger than sperm (*protandry*) or b) protect a harem (*protogyny*).

Which features should a world have to make this system the default for most land vertebrates, including mammals?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151441/discussion-on-question-by-crissov-which-environment-would-favor-sequential-sexes); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Perhaps a little disappointing not to see more open votes now that it's been edited, ***"are there any environmental factors we know of that might tend to encourage or discourage the evolution of this over other reproductive strategies"*** (what this question essentially reads as to me now it's been edited) seems a reasonable question to me? I don't think it's a great one, and I think the answer is pretty obviously no, but that's not a close reason and it might still potentially spit up an interesting answer from some aware of some bit of research or science the rest of us aren't.

Comment: @Pelinore It's asking for features that would 'normalize' the presented system. The titular question seems to narrow it down to environmental features, but it still seems slightly brainstormy to me. To OP: " I assume it would only develop in a world where it’s the/a common sexual model" seems to be circular reasoning (unless "it" does not refer to "the/a common sexual model"): can you clarify this?

Comment: @Joachim a "No, it's just chance what develops first and then by virtue of being first comes to dominate" likely with supporting reference to what can be extrapolated from the fossil record of how four limbs and other features came to dominate seems a potential non-circular answer to me? I'm not sure I consider something evidence led like that brain-stormy, certainly not in the 'lets make stuff up until we hit on something that sounds cool / throw random ideas at the wall to see what sticks' sense at least.