# Evolution of animals with more than two sexes

Tags: evolution, xenobiology

On Earth, while there are organisms with more than two sexes, especially fungi with their many "mating types", such breeding systems have never evolved on larger creatures, the main hypothesis for this being that two is the least amout of sexes required to maintain genetic diversity and that evolution will prefer the simplest solution. My question is: Could there be a reason for multiple sexes to evolve on animals instead of the two sexes we see on Earth?

Comment: This one is probably closer:   https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/579/is-it-possible-for-a-species-to-have-more-than-two-sexes/14530#14530

Comment: *"the main hypothesis for this being that two is the least amount of sexes required to maintain genetic diversity and that evolution will prefer the simplest solution"* I very much doubt that is *main hypothesis* .. it is far more likely simply the fact that the ***more*** of  a species you require to get together for reproduction to happen the less likely it is to happen and the more likely they are to go extinct, over the long term the odds will simply kill them off, especially if there are any competitors that only need two or one.